# PHP use current machine timezone

Tags: php, windows, timezone

Is there a way to force PHP to use the timezone of the machine it's running on (windows in my case).

I have been looking for a while and can't find an answer, is it really impossible using convenient methods (exec is not an option)?

EDIT:

I have a windows server with time zone set to UTC+2. It runs apache with PHP, the problem is that PHP is using UTC time zone for time operations instead of UTC+2. 
Is there a way for php to automatically use systems time zone without need of defining it in php.ini or setting explicitly in script?

Comment: If you want the server to use the client's time-zone you'll have to use JavaScript.  Other than that there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Usually the default timezone, if you don't set one, is the machine's timezone. Is this not the case in your setup?

Comment: That makes even less sense. You need to explain yourself more clearly. But it seems you would like PHP (on the server) to use the time of the computer that is connecting to the server (the client). this cannot really be done. If you can explain what you are attempting to accomplish though, I am sure a solution can be found for you.

Comment: @oxguy3 no it uses UTC and system time is UTC+2

Comment: Seems that solution of duplicate question uses exec which I can't use.